# Why are particles only covering half of a face?

Tags: particles, weight-painting, hair

Applying particles to a face, they are only being applied to half the face:

[image: Image of object with particles over half of top face.]

This occurs both with Eevee and Cycles. It also occurs in all viewport shading modes, and a full render. This occurs regardless of the seed used. The problem is not with the weight painting - in fact, the problem does not occur in weight painting mode:

[image: Image of weight painting mode, with correct particle distribution.]

It only occurs in object mode (and the full render). The split appears to be along the 45-degree angle between the x- and y-axes. How do I fix this please? Thank you.

Comment: Chack the order of the modifiers, mirror modifier should be after the particles.

Comment: I don't have a mirror modifier. Do I need to add one?

Comment: [Adding another comment because can't edit] It turned out to be the subdivision modifier! I moved it to below the particle modifier and it fixed it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@no-can-do](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/99407/no-can-do)'s [comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201922/why-are-particles-only-covering-half-of-a-face#comment339202_201922):

Switching the positions of the modifiers fixes the problem. Just place the *Particle* modifier above the *Subdivision* modifier.